# automate sending messages in google hangouts from unix server

Tags: unix, google-api, hangouts-api

Is there a way that I could automate sending messages to a group in google hangouts using its API from my UNIX box? I am trying to automate a sql query which in turn sends the result as instant message to google hangouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Hangouts does not currently have an API for chat. You can star this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=796) to show your interest though.